# Can't create Wordpress docker on Windows

Tags: windows-10, docker, wordpress

From [this page](https://docs.docker.com/compose/wordpress/), I have created c:\users\steve\Documents\Docker\Wordpress\docker-compose.yml, containing:

```
version: '2'

services:
   db:
     image: mysql:5.7
     volumes:
       - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
     restart: always
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: wordpress
       MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
       MYSQL_USER: wordpress
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress

   wordpress:
     depends_on:
       - db
     image: wordpress:latest
     ports:
       - "8000:80"
     restart: always
     environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
volumes:
    db_data:
```

When I open a cmd shell or powershell, navigate to C:\users\steve\Documents\Docker\Wordpress, and run

```
docker-compose up -d
```

I receive:

```
Traceback (most recent call
  File "<string>", line 3, i
  File "compose\cli\main.py"
  File "compose\cli\main.py"
  File "compose\cli\main.py"
  File "compose\project.py",
  File "compose\project.py",
  File "site-packages\docker
  File "site-packages\docker
  File "site-packages\docker
  File "site-packages\reques
  File "site-packages\reques
  File "site-packages\reques
  File "site-packages\reques
  File "site-packages\reques
  File "site-packages\reques
  File "httplib.py", line 10
  File "httplib.py", line 10
  File "httplib.py", line 10
  File "httplib.py", line 88
  File "httplib.py", line 84
  File "site-packages\docker
  File "site-packages\docker
  File "site-packages\docker
pywintypes.error: (2, 'WaitN
docker-compose returned -1
```

When I run `docker-compose up -d > output.txt`, `output.txt` is empty. If I run `docker-compose > output.txt` I receive the help contents in the `cmd` screen, and nothing in `output.txt`.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Could you please pipe the output of docker-compose to a log file? Seems like most of the output has been cropped by your commandshell.

I just used your composefile on an ubuntu machine and can confirm that wordpress is indeed firing up, so I guess we'll have to check what's wrong with your environment.

Comment: Thanks @PatrickR. When I run `docker-compose up -d > output.txt`, `output.txt` is empty. If I run `docker-compose > output.txt` I receive the help contents in the `cmd` screen, and nothing in `output.txt`.

Comment: You might want to drop the `-d` flag while you're debugging this: `docker-compose up > output.txt`. This should show you any stdout from the container.

Comment: On another note, which version of Docker for Windows are you using? Did you try completely reinstallting with a current version? Is Hyper-V enabled? Any other hypervisors on your machine?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it can't find a file. Please check your `PATH` and make sure it points to your Python installation.

This guy had a similar problem:

> Well, it looks like I had this setup in my path:
>
> C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Scripts
>   C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\
>
> I don't know how that was set or what installed that, perhaps docker
>   toolbox? Not sure, but once I changed the path to be pointed to
>   python2.7 in my windows environment, then everything started working
>   correctly and it pulled all the images that I needed for this.
>
> Thanks for your prompt response.

[Source](https://github.com/shipping-docker/php-app/issues/19)